# Automatically add links to strings of keywords

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

In my article, I want to automatically add links to keywords.
My keywords array:

```
 $keywords = [
       0=>['id'=>1,'slug'=>'getName','url'=>'https://example.com/1'],
       1=>['id'=>2,'slug'=>'testName','url'=>'https://example.com/2'],
       2=>['id'=>3,'slug'=>'ign','url'=>'https://example.com/3'],
    ];
```

This is my code:

```
private function keywords_replace(string $string, array $key_array)
{
    $array_first = $key_array;
    $array_last = [];
    foreach ($array_first as $key=>$value)
    {
        $array_last[$key] = [$key, $value['slug'], '<a target="_blank" href="' . $value['url'] . '" title="' . $value['slug'] . '">' . $value['slug'] . '</a>'];
    }
    $count = count($array_last);
    for ($i=0; $i<$count;$i++)
    {
        for ($j=$count-1;$j>$i;$j--)
        {
            if (strlen($array_last[$j][1]) > strlen($array_last[$j-1][1]))
            {
                $tmp = $array_last[$j];
                $array_last[$j] = $array_last[$j-1];
                $array_last[$j-1] = $tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    $keys = $array_last;
    foreach ($keys as $key)
    {
        $string = str_ireplace($key[1],$key[0],$string);
    }
    foreach ($keys as $key)
    {
        $string = str_ireplace($key[0],$key[2],$string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

result:

```
 $str = "<p>Just a test: getName  testName";
 echo $this->keywords_replace($str,$keywords);
```

like this:Just a test: [getName](https://example.com/1) [testName](https://example.com/2)
**very import: If the string has no spaces, it will not match.Because I will use other languages, sentences will not have spaces like English. Like Wordpress key words auto link**

I think my code is not perfect，Is there a better algorithm to implement this function? Thanks!

Comment: Show your expected array example

Comment: I added the effect after the output.

Comment: Are your slugs mostly camelCase, or rather do you care about case insensitivity?

Comment: I don't care about capitalizing lowercase and camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace all occurrences of the `slug` words in your string with the corresponding `url` values:

```
$keywords = [
       0=>['id'=>1,'slug'=>'getName','url'=>'https://www.getname.com'],
       1=>['id'=>2,'slug'=>'testName','url'=>'https://www.testname.com'],
       2=>['id'=>3,'slug'=>'ign','url'=>'https://www.ign.com'],
    ];
$str = "<p>Just a test: getName  testName";
echo array_reduce($keywords, function ($c, $v) { return preg_replace('/\\b(' . $v['slug'] . ')\\b/', $v['url'], $c); }, $str);
```

Output:

```
<p>Just a test: https://www.getname.com https://www.testname.com
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/VsDLQ)

**Update**

To change the text into links, you need to use this:

```
echo array_reduce($keywords, 
                  function ($c, $v) { 
                     return preg_replace('/\\b(' . $v['slug'] . ')\\b/',
                                         '<a href="'. $v['url'] . '">$1</a>', $c);
                  }, 
                  $str);
```

Output:

```
<p>Just a test: <a href="https://www.getname.com">getName</a> <a href="https://www.testname.com">testName</a>
```

[Updated demo](https://3v4l.org/BN06C)

**Update 2**

Because some of the links that are being substituted include words that are also values of `slug`, it's necessary to do all the replacements at once using the array format of [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php). We build an array of patterns and replacements using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) and [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), then pass that to `strtr`:

```
$reps = array_combine(array_column($keywords, 'slug'),
                      array_map(function ($k) { return '<a href="' . $k['url'] .'">' . $k['slug'] . '</a>'; }, $keywords
                      ));
$newstr = strtr($str, $reps);
```

[New demo](https://3v4l.org/r1LpD)

Comment: The keyword is not replaced with url, changed to <a></a>

Comment: @DomainRocker sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I think I have what you want now.

Comment: If the string has no spaces, it will not match.Because I will use other languages, sentences will not have spaces like English.

Comment: @DomainRocker you can just remove the `\\b` from the regex and that will stop it looking for spaces. Note that you might also need to use the `u` modifier to the regex if you have unicode characters. If you could edit your question with some other sample text I'd be happy to edit my answer to meet those requirements.

Comment: @DomainRocker I've added a new update and demo based on yours. It works for your sample data.

Comment: If there are keywords in the <img> and <a> tags in $str, how can I exclude them?

Comment: It's not reasonable to keep changing the question like this. Please start again with a new question, and include **all** the possible use cases. That way you won't waste our time coming up with new answers and your time finding out they don't work because you missed one of the use cases.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change structure of array to key/value using loop that result stored in `$newKeywords`. Then using `preg_replace_callback()` select every word in string and check that it exist in key of array. If exist, wrap it in anchor tag.

```
$newKeywords = [];
foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
    $newKeywords[$keyword['slug']] = $keyword['url'];

$newStr = preg_replace_callback("/(\w+)/", function($m) use($newKeywords){
    return isset($newKeywords[$m[0]]) ? "<a href='{$newKeywords[$m[0]]}'>{$m[0]}</a>" : $m[0];
}, $str);
```

Output:

```
<p>Just a test: <a href='https://www.getname.com'>getName</a>  <a href='https://www.testname.com'>testName</a></p>
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/ev7V1)

Comment: thank you very much, I first saw the preg_replace_callback function.

Comment: If the string has no spaces, it will not match.Because I will use other languages, sentences will not have spaces like English.

Answer (score 1):

My answer uses preg_replace as does [Nick's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944465/3392762) above.

It relies on the patterns and replacements being equally sized arrays, with corresponding patterns and replacements.

Word boundaries need to be respected, which I doubt you can do with a simple string replacement.

```
<?php
$keywords = [
    0=>['id'=>1,'slug'=>'foo','url'=>'https://www.example.com/foo'],
    1=>['id'=>2,'slug'=>'bar','url'=>'https://www.example.com/bar'],
    2=>['id'=>3,'slug'=>'baz','url'=>'https://www.example.com/baz'],
];

foreach ($keywords as $item)
{
    $patterns[]     = '@\b(' . $item['slug'] . ')\b@i';
    $replacements[] = '<a href="' . $item['url'] . '">$1</a>';
}

$html = "<p>I once knew a barbed man named <i>Foo</i>, he often visited the bar.</p>";

print preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $html);
```

Output:

```
<p>I once knew a barbed man named <i><a href="https://www.example.com/foo">Foo</a></i>, he often visited the <a href="https://www.example.com/bar">bar</a>.</p>
```

Comment: If you don't want to replace all occurrences of the slug, you can use the fourth parameter on preg_replace to something like 1, so you are not swamped with links.

Comment: If the string has no spaces, it will not match.Because I will use other languages, sentences will not have spaces like English

Comment: @DomainRocker, but your example string has spaces.

Comment: @DomainRocker, for your example _ign_ slug in your question, what happens if you don't have word boundaries then such as spaces?  If say I have the word: _ignominious_?

Comment: I mean in the case of other languages,such as Chinese,there is no space in a sentence.So I can't match the keyword.

Comment: @DomainRocker, I can't see a 'one size fits all' solution here for different languages.  The regex `\b` modifier seems to be locale dependent.  A good detailed link of its nuances would be appreciated.  Do update your samples as your requirements are not clearly specified.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer: thanks for @Nick

```
$content = array_reduce($keywords , function ($c, $v) {
    return preg_replace('/(>[^<>]*?)(' . $v['slug'] . ')([^<>]*?<)/', '$1<a href="'. $v['url'] . '">$2</a>$3', $c);
}, $str);
```